# Query all the entities where list property contains everything in another list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have 3 entities, users, tasks and permissions.  Users can have many permissions.  Tasks also have many permission associated with them.  The idea that I am trying to capture in my query is this:  My tasks need to be done by users with all the correct permissions required by the task.

I am struggling with the query.  I think this is what I need:

```
var userList = context.Users
                      .Include("Permissions")
                      .Where(x => neededPermissionFromTask.Except(x.Permissions).Count() == 0).ToList();
```

But I get an exception:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Permission'. Only primitive
>   types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this
>   context.

Appreciate any help, suggestions or  comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing list of Permission objects, pass ids of those permissions:

```
var ids = neededPermissionFromTask.Select(p => p.Id).ToList();
var userList = 
     context.Users.Include("Permissions")
            .Where(u => ids.Except(u.Permissions.Select(p => p.Id)).Count() == 0)
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is caused by your list `neededPermissionFromTask` - the Entity Framework has no idea how to deal with a list of `Permission` objects.

I would suggest something like this - find all users having all the permissions required by the task with ID `taskId`.

```
var users = context.Users
                   .Where(user => context.Tasks
                                         .Single(task => task.Id == taskId)
                                         .Permissions
                                         .All(permission => user.Permissions
                                                                .Contains(permission)))
                   .ToList();
```

I am not sure if `Permissions.Contains(permission)` will work - it might cause the same error as mentioned in the question. But there is an easy way around - instead of looking if the object is contained in the set just look for an object with the same ID.